# Fridge magnets in San Francisco!

Tags: usa, shopping, california, san-francisco, souvenirs

From every destination, I buy a magnet (you know the ones we put in the fridge) that is strongly connected to that destination. Now for a guy that has been to several Greek Islands, (<sub>[and not only](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/travel/)</sub>), you can understand that buying something special matters, something unique!

**Is there any place that sells (special/nice/beautiful/distinctive) magnets in San Francisco?**

---

For example, from Monaco I bought a magnet that was like a wall-frame, and my mother found it marvelous! I really want to bring her one that she will find special..

---

A negative answer would be also accepted (i.e. that every store that sells souvenirs is pretty much the same for magnets).

Comment: @GayotFow but [tag:shopping] says to be specific and it has 1.1k followers...! Moreover, I am pretty sure my question is *related to **Travel***, but if there is a rule, there should be something done about the tag too... :)

Comment: We have a specific name for these in English, "fridge magnets". If you just say "magnet" we imagine a red horseshoe shaped lump of iron with shiny ends. I suggest editing your question title to say "fridge magnets". Everybody knows that these are commonly collected souvenirs, like snowglobes etc.

Comment: @GayotFow: Re-read the shopping rules. We're not allowed to take "price shopping" questions. That is we can't find you the cheapest backpack or plane ticket of a specific type/date. We can help you find a souvenir you're having trouble locating.

Comment: Done @hippietrail, you are right! I don't want anyone to believe that I am interesting in buying a [Magnemite](https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/magnemite.jpg)! :) Fantastic news, Gayot I assure you I am not even considering the price factor here!!! :)))

Comment: @hippietrail jolly good, I'm retracting my close vote, thanks for the explanation

Comment: You can buy fridge magnets almost in any touristic attraction in San Francisco. But if you are looking for somewhere specialized/organized I've seen a couple of big stores of touristic souvenirs around Fisherman's Wharf. Or you could go to Chinatown as already answered below, they will sell the same stuff for cheaper prices. The only drawback is that the stores there are smaller so you may have to visit a few of them to find exactly what you are looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, Chinatown is Ground Zero for these kind of knickknacks.  Cable-car magnets, Transamerica-Pyramid magnets, Golden-Gate-Bridge magnets, whatever you need.

They are all made in China, of course, but given that it is Chinatown, I don't know if that makes them more or less authentic.

Comment: OP, if you are after something fancier than the typical fridge magnet souvenirs, you should add a bit more details about that to the question. To me I could read your question both ways so I wasn't sure.

Comment: I am sure for fancy the OP can try their luck at Pier 1 or similar.

Comment: I posted my question after visiting some stores in Chinatown and near Union square, but I don't know if I had visited them all around there, that's why I didn't mention it. Pier 1 @BurhanKhalid? I haven't been there *yet*. ;)

Comment: I think Burhan was making something of a joke.  San Francisco has a waterfront and the piers are numbered -- Pier 39 being the most famous -- but the first pier is part of the Ferry Building, which is an upscale food court and, as you'd guess, a ferry terminal; no fridge magnets.  The "Pier 1" he was referring to is [a chain store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pier_1_Imports) that specializes in home furnishings and decor.  There is one near the corner of Geary and Stanyon, but there are over a 1000 stores across North America.

Comment: Ah thanks! I did actually buy two from Pier 39! ;)

Comment: Yesterday afternoon I noticed an artisan at the top of the Embarcadero BART station selling a huge array of magnets made from photographs of SF landmarks.  If you're still in town, you should check it out.